# Laravel Sorting via url

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add simple sorting to my index pages, but I am coming into conflict when I try to include search results or add an additional query to the URL. Here is what I currently have:

**Controller**

```
// Search default
if ($request->search == null) {
    $search = '';
} else {
    $search = $request->search;
}

// Sort default
if ($request->sort == null) {
    $sort = 'asc';
} else {
    $sort = $request->sort;
}

$doctors = Doctor::orderBy('last_name', $sort)
    ->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('type', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('npi', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('license', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('dea', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->paginate(10);

return view('doctors.index')->with('doctors', $doctors);
```

**Blade**

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'GET']) }}
    {{ Form::text('search', null, ['class' => 'form-control form-control-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Search Doctors...']) }}
    {{Form::submit('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'])}}
{{ Form::close() }}

@if(Request::input('sort', 'asc') == 'asc')
    <a href="?sort=desc">Name</a>
@else 
    <a href="?sort=asc">Name</a>
@endif
```

Now, independently, the `?search=` and the `?sort=` will work. But if I try to search for something, then sort the results, it clears out the search request. I also have other columns such as License#, Address, etc that I want to add so that people can sort by more than just the Name. However, when I change the requests to add a `?sortBy=` such as`<a href="?sortBy=name?sort=desc">Name</a>`, the sort direction no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

The URL query params need to be separated by `&` not `?` like so:

`<a href="?sortBy=name&sort=desc">Name</a>`

Comment: Thank you! I've changed my if statements to be more similar to `<a href="?sortBy=last_name&sort=desc">Name</a>`, which covers the sortBy and the sorting direction. However, I am still unable to figure out the search functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to append the query to `$doctors`:

```
$doctors->addQuery('sort', request()->get('sort'))->addQuery('sortBy', request()->get('sortBy'))
```

Edit:

It appears the api changed for later versions, so use `appends`:

```
->appends(['sort' => request()->get('sort'), 'sortBy' => request()->get('sortBy')])
```